# Change volume and popup menu

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, popupmenu

I have an application that plays music. For each track, I can call a context menu.

The problem is that Android 2.2, when I call the menu, hardware volume keys do not work.
In the version Android 3.2 works correctly, that is i can change music volume with open pop-up menu. 
Is it possible to do the same behavior for version 2.2?

Update:

I apologize for my mistake for those who read this post earlier. The problem does not occur with the standard context menu, and a class that inherits from PopupWindow. This class is responsible for displaying the menu and when grabs focus, it can not handle the sound pressing a button on a mobile phone (for version 2.2, as I wrote above).
If you take away the focus, the application will not behave properly.
As an option, I would like to block the Activity at a time when we call the menu, as is done for the standard context menu, that is, to be able to handle just clicking inside the pop-up window, and the remaining area is shaded.
Someone knows how to do it?

Comment: paste your code to show what have you done for that

Comment: I do not have a separate code in which I tried to do something, just when you call a pop-up menu hardware volume keys do not work, if system version is 2.2, and in 3.2 and above all good. I want to know whether it is possible to change this behavior on android 2.2.